# Sign up/Login Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Sorry for the novice question but I am trying to get to grips with RoR. I have a very basic sign up and login process in place but am having some difficulty getting the routing correct. I am also unsure whether I am actually being logged out successfully when I push my logout button because it isn't then displaying the login button as it should.

My setup is as follows on Rails 3.1:

Sessions Controller

> class SessionsController < ApplicationController
>       def new
>       end
>
> ```
> def create
>     user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
>     if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
>         session[:user_id] = user.id
>         redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
>     else
>         flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password!"
>         render "signup"
>     end
> end
>
> def destroy
>     session[:user_id] = nil
>     redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged Out!"
> ```
>
> end 
>      end

User Controller

> class UserController < ApplicationController
>        def new
>           @user = User.new
>         end
>
> ```
>   def create
>     @user = User.new (params[:user])
>   if @user.save
>     redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed Up!"
>   else
>     render "user/new"
>   end
>  end
> end
> ```

User Model

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
> has_secure_password
> validates_confirmation_of :password
> validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
> validates_presence_of :email
> validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :create
>
> end
> ```

Sessions/new.html.erb

> ```
>  <h1>Log In</h1>
>
>  <%= form_tag login_path do %>
> <div class="field">
>     <%= label_tag :email %>
>     <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
> </div>
>
> <div class ="field">
>     <%= label_tag :password %>
>     <%= password_field_tag :password %>
> </div>
>
> <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></div>
> <%end%>
> ```

User/new.html.erb

> ```
> <% if session[:user_id] %>
>    <!-- user is logged in -->
>    <%= link_to logout_path %>
>   <% else %>
>   <!-- user is not logged in -->
>    <%= link_to login_path %>
> <% end %>
>
> <h1>Sign Up</h1>
> ```
>
> `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
>       <% if @user.errors.any? %>
>           <div class="error_messages">
>            <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
>               <ul>
>                   <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
>                       <li><%= message %></li>
>                   <% end %>
>               </ul>
>           </div>
>       <% end %>`
>
> ```
> <div class = "field">
>     <%= f.label :email %>
>     <%= f.text_field :email %>
> </div>
>
> <div class = "field">
>     <%= f.label :password %>
>     <%= f.password_field :password %>
> </div>
>
> <div class = "field">
>     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
>     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
> </div>
>
> <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
> <% end %>
> ```

Finally my Routes file

> ```
> MadeByV2::Application.routes.draw do
>
> controller :user do
> get "signup" => "user#new"
> end
>
> resources :users
>
>  controller :sessions do
>   get "login" => "sessions#new"
>   post "login" => "sessions#create"
>   delete "logout" => "sessions#destroy"
>  end
> root :to => "user#new"
> ```
>
> end

Sorry for the extensive use of code in this post but I figure it's best to give a well rounded view of everything so people can see where I am going wrong.

Any help you can offer really would be much appreciated because I don't seem to be getting it myself

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: It looks as though your link_to's are wrong ...
try changing <%= link_to logout_path %> to `<%= link_to "Logout",logout_path, :method => :delete %>`  and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Matenia, thanks for your help I have added this into my code and it looks and works alot better now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but your routes look a little strange.

I'd try something like this:

```
resources :users
resources :sessions
match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

Then I think everything you've currently got should work.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help I managed to incorporate this into my routes file and everything seems to be working perfectly now!